# Android layout question - multiple widgets

Tags: android

I want to create a screen that has a column of scrollable images on the left and a similar  column on the right with space in between them. The user selects an image in the left column and based on that selection, the images in the right column get filled up. I can drag images from the right column into the space in between to create a composite image.

What kind of layout should I use to accomplish this? Is this one view or three views? Is this a Vertical Linear Layout with three columns and do I need to use Grid view in the left and right columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the left-hand list of views is a `ListView`. The right-hand list of views is a `ListView`. The middle...I have no idea, since I do not know what you mean by "create a composite image". It might be a `ListView`, it might be a vertical `LinearLayout`, it might be something else.

The three columns (`ListView`, thingy, `ListView`) are probably formed via a horizontal `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`.